# .net MVC Get Post Return View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

usually I would setup a GET POST Redirect cycle, however I have run into a situation where rather than redirecting, I need to just return a new view. The problem with this is that the new page has the URL of the previous page (because I haven't redirected, i've just returned a new view). Is there any way of changing the url of page presented to the user without redirecting?

I am actually implementing a wizard where I need to persist data between pages, however I have no way to persist data through a redirect (TempData is disabled..) which led to the above approach. A possible solution is to create a table to store the temporary data that I need to persist but this is undesirable. I also don't want to end up with one view with every field for the wizard and just use jscript to hide show the different steps.

Any help, tips or general advice would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, you would have to redirect to change the URL effectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can always POST to a new URL, right?

In your wizard, you could do

1. myWizard/step1
2. myWizars/step2
3. etc

There's no problem with that, except that they'll repost if they hit F5.

Between the the posts, you can model bind and then print out html hiddens.

ViewState 2.0

Comment: thanks for the replies. I can keep my data by posting it and returning it as the model, that's not a problem. But if I post to the next step, then I can't do some validation and go back to the same page without a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your View a strongly-type view so that you can pass your data to that view when you return it.  Just make a view-model out of the data you want to persist.

```
return View("MyViewPage", objData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could do something like this?

1. Wrap the view with your form up in a partial.
2. Have it post to the second URL.
3. Perform validation and return the same partial if it fails.
4. Otherwise, return your second view.

You'll have to make your form a child action in order to stop the `PartialViewResult` from being the entire rendered markup on the POST, though (and post to the parent action), so this does have some limitations in terms of what you'll be able to render (e.g. you might have some issues to work around if you want your layout to change for the second page).

This way you can keep your `ModelState` intact for your validation errors, return your second view directly from the POST and still have a different URL.